# how to populate a table in HTML from SQL query

Tags: html, sql, razor

I have a basic html page that I want to display a table on, populated from a SQL query.

I want to display all part numbers that are classified as essential items, that are out of stock.

I'm using CSHTML, razor syntax on webmatrix.
I tried this:

`var nilstock = db.QueryValue("select STOCKCODE, TOTALSTOCK from dbo.STOCK_ITEMS where STOCK_CLASSIFICATION in(170,190,200) and TOTALSTOCK <1 order by STOCKCODE");`

I then call this var later, by`@nilstock.ToString()` or even just `@nilstick` but it returns only the first affected cell.

Any help gratefully accepted..:)

Comment: I'm not familiar with this stack but it seems to me like `QueryValue` would return a single value instead of a full result set.

Comment: OK, so should i just have query?

Comment: Try that and see what it does.

Comment: No. Still gives me a single result: the first part number in the results.

Comment: Whoops, correct response : now runs error: System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[System.Object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your query from a single value to return a whole dataset, then iterate through the items as in Stefan's answer. The whole chunk of code should look like this:

```
@{
    // Open database connection etc
    var nilstock = db.Query("select STOCKCODE, TOTALSTOCK from dbo.STOCK_ITEMS where STOCK_CLASSIFICATION in(170,190,200) and TOTALSTOCK <1 order by STOCKCODE");
}

<table>
@foreach(var row in nilstock)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@row.STOCKCODE</td>
        <td>@row.TOTALSTOCK</td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks also to @stefan for his help

Comment: @jraede we've got our answer - you weren't far off!

Comment: @Bevan Yeah, it was the two answers together that you needed! For reference, your database command methods are `db.Execute()` for things that return nothing but number of rows affected (inserts, etc), `db.QueryValue()` for queries that return a single value from a single row, `db.QuerySingle()` that returns a single row and, as in this answer, `db.Query()` which can return any number of fields and any number of rows.

Comment: Thanks! Good follow thru. I'll store those, coz I'll be bound to need them soon!

Answer (score 1):

Not that familiar with how you query the db, but you probably have iterate over the result set like this:

```
<table>
    @foreach(var n in nilstock)
    {
        <tr><td>@n.STOCKCODE</td><td>@n.TOTALSTOCK</td></tr>
    }
<table>
```

Comment: Hmmm... Now it crashes with reason: `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'char' does not contain a definition for 'STOCKCODE'`

Comment: I'm sure you're on the right track though, because it's trying to do it, there just seems to be some declaration bug somewhere...